# How to use disMax query parser in solr

Tags: solr, scoring, dismax

What is dismax query parser and how to use it. I just want to search for a string in a field in solr by its matching percentage. how to use it getting this done. Please give an example how to use dismax query parser.
i have the following document. and i just to get the document which matches fully or partially with the `q=Jain Nagar Bla Bla`

```
{
   "id":"2",
   "shipping_firstname":"Sudhanshu",
   "address":"H.No. 444, Gali No.2 Jain Nagar",
   "date_added":"2017-01-21T14:15:15Z",
   "_version_":1562029999829024768}]
}
```

I am using this query

```
select?q=Jain Nagar&defType=dismax&m‌​m=2&pf=address&qf=ad‌​dress
```

Why it doesn't give any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mm` (Minimum Should Match) Parameter of dismax parser.

it has great flexibility to specify Integers or percentage to mm parameter.

Example:

consider 3 docs

> doc1:  duplicate ipod, doc2:ipod apple, doc3: ipod cable

Lets say query `ipod apple`. it retrieve docs if it has term either `ipod` or `apple` or both. so we get 3 results.

if we use mm=2 with dismax parser

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/select?indent=on&q=ipod apple&wt=json&defType=dismax&mm=2
```

It fetch docs minimum match of 2 words, specified in query `ipod apple`.
if doc has only one term (say 'ipod') it wont be returned in results.

In result we get only one doc, i.e

> doc2

can also specify percentage values to `mm` parameter(like 75% or -25%)

for more details check [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm%28MinimumShouldMatch%29Parameter)

Hope this helps, vinod

Comment: i have field address in document having different address values. and i am trying this query.  and query is like `solr/orders/select?q=Jain%20Nagar&defType=dismax&indent=on&mm=2&pf=address&qf=address` it return nothing, but i have `H.No. 444, Gali No.2 Jain Nagar` in document's address field. All i want to do is to make a partial search. It means that if some words in query are matching in address field, i want to display them

Comment: check schema file for address field and its Type definition. is It set index=true.  what analyzers used for that fieldType?

Comment: its like `<field name="address" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />`

Comment: may be the string type is not analyzed. change type other field type which has proper analyzers. try text_general / any other type which uses class=solr.TextField. remeber if modify schema, you should restart solr and reindex.

Comment: i have one more question. if `address: H.No. 444, Gali No.2 Jain Nagar` in document and if `q=Jian Nagar` the it should also consider `Jian` is matched with `Jain`. is it possible..??

Comment: yes. fuzzy string match. ex: `q=jian~0.1`  it searches for other token which has Levenshtein distance close to 0.1 with term jian.  it will match jain,  value should be 0 to 1.