# DisMax query parser is not running

Tags: solr, dismax

Environment- solr-8.9.0

Movies data in a form of a .csv file has been indexed in apache solr.

Movies data

```
name,directed_by,genre,type,id,initial_release_date
.45,Gary Lennon,Black comedy|Thriller|Psychological thriller|Indie film|Action Film|Crime Thriller|Crime Fiction|Drama,,/en/45_2006,2006-11-30
9,Shane Acker,Computer Animation|Animation|Apocalyptic and post-apocalyptic fiction|Science Fiction|Short Film|Thriller|Fantasy,,/en/9_2005,2005-04-21
Bomb the System,Adam Bhala Lough,Crime Fiction|Indie film|Coming of age|Drama,,/en/bomb_the_system,
movie_name,Adam Bhala,Animation|Indie film|Coming of age|Drama,,/en/bomb_the_system,
```

The DisMax Query Parser has been run over the field 'directed_by'. 'directed_by' field is mapped as a 'text_general' field-type in managed-schema.

I have run the following query over solr

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/testCore1/select --data-urlencode "q=directed_by:'Adam Bhala Lough~'" --data-urlencode "defType=dismax" --data-urlencode "mm=2"
```

but the above query is giving 0 'numFound' in response.
I expect the following field to match:

```
Adam Bhala
Adam Bhala Lough
```

I expect the following field not to match:

```
Adam Gary Lennon
```

Although data is indexed in solr. I have cross-checked this by running the following query without disMax query parser and it is giving responses.

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/testCore1/select --data-urlencode "q=directed_by:'Adam Bhala Lough~'"
```

Why dismax query parser is not running as it should be? I understand that mm(Minimum Should Match) Parameter===> defines the minimum number of clauses that must match.

I have spent hours to solve this. However, I cannot seem to find anything that holds my hand.
Could someone help me find the missing piece?

Reference
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/the-dismax-query-parser.html

[How to use disMax query parser in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834214/how-to-use-dismax-query-parser-in-solr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`qf`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/the-dismax-query-parser.html#qf-query-fields-parameter) (query fields) parameter to specify in which field(s) the search should be performed, along with (optionally) a boost factor used to increase or decrease that particular field’s importance in the query (defaults to 1) :

```
q=Adam Bhala Lough~
qf=directed_by
```

Or, use [`edismax`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html) query parser instead of `dismax`, so that the standard query syntax you were using (`directed_by:'Adam Bhala Lough~'`) can work as intended.